Removing hypotheses of convergence of total masses in Portmanteau theorem

This is the statement of Portmanteau theorem in Klenke's book. I was wondering under what assumptions you can remove the hypotheses of the total masses at the points $(vii) $ and $(viii)$ since in many probability books I haven't seen this hypotheses.
To be precise I’m wondering if there some assumptions on the measures and/or the space under which vague convergence implies weak one without assuming convergence of the total mass.
Thanks

Are you asking when (vague convergence + some other assumption) implies weak convergence?

Exactly, I’ll edit the post to make it clearer

An example: if $E$ is a locally compact metric space then (vague convergence + tightness of $(\mu_n)_n$) implies weak convergence and mass preservation. You can find the complete statement of the theorem in Schilling Th.21.17 p. 252
